# In Oracle SQL, what are the keywords that represent a numeric value?

Tags: oracle

I'm writing code that generates SQL queries based on string parameters. When building the query, I check if the compared value in the WHERE part of the statement is a word or a number, and based on that I add apostrophes.

The problem is that there are some keywords which represent a numeric value, for example sysdate, so I'd like to compare the input word against a list of keywords which represent a numeric value.

I executed the command:

```
select * from V$RESERVED_WORDS
```

but was given over 1000 keywords, and a lot of them are irrelevant (like SELECT). Is there a way to get a list of only keywords that have a numeric value?

Comment: `sysdate` doesn't represent a "numeric" value, it represents a `DATE`

Comment: I'd strongly advise against such an approach. This will cause you problems without end in the future - e.g. is '5' a numeric value? What about '5.4', '.4' (american style without leading 0), '4,3' (German decimal separator), '0.7E-17' (scientific notation), '20150319' (either a number or today's date),... ?

Comment: Rather than look at the type of data passed in the value for the WHERE, look at the data type of the column that you are using (you can query it from `user_tab_columns`)... `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` will always need to be treated differently, of course, rather than just quoting or not

Answer (score 1):

> When building the query, I check if the compared value in the WHERE part of the statement is a word or a number, and based on that I add apostrophes.

You might be a victim of a bad design. You must know your database design well enough before developing the code. Irrespective, whether it is just plain `SQL` or `PL/SQL`. Especially, when it comes to **data types**, you must be as accurate as possible to use the appropriate data type, in order to make sure that the **Oracle optimizer** acts the way it is designed. Else, you would end up rectifying the performance bottlenecks.

> some keywords which represent a numeric value, for example sysdate,

`SYSDATE` is a `DATE` data type, not a `NUMBER` data type in Oracle.

Instead of listing all the **reserved keywords**, I would try to list down the **data types** which you are looking for:

**NOTE** I have not explicitly mentioned the **PL/SQL** data types like `PLS_INTEGER` etc. since your question explicitly says **In Oracle SQL**.

**number_datatypes::=**

> - NUMBER
> - BINARY_FLOAT
> - BINARY_DOUBLE

**ANSI_supported_datatypes::=**

> - NUMERIC
> - DECIMAL
> - DEC
> - INTEGER
> - INT
> - SMALLINT
> - FLOAT
> - DOUBLE
> - REAL

I have tried to summarize from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI030).

**EDIT**

Perhaps it might be helpful, so adding a link to `PL/SQL` data types documentation. Here it is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#i46029

Comment: I think the OP is looking for values that represent numbers, such as `NaN`, rather than data types. Outside of `CAST`, you rarely see data types in DML.

Comment: Well, OP's question is **what are the keywords that represent a numeric value?** Also his attempt to query the reserved keywords lead me to answer accordingly. I am waiting for OP's response.